# Prove that in a real inner product space $V$ an endomorphism $f$ is skew-Hermitian if and only if $\langle v,f(\vec v)\rangle=0$ for all $v\in V$

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, solution-verification, inner-products, skew-symmetric-matrices

> **Definition**
>
> Let be $V$ and $U$ real vector spaces equipped with an inner product. So given a linear transformation $f:V\rightarrow U$ a function $f^*:U\rightarrow V$ is called the *adjoint* of $f$ if
> $$
> \langle\vec u,f(\vec v)\rangle=\langle f^*(\vec u),\vec v\rangle
> $$
> for all $\vec v\in V$ and for all $\vec u\in U$. In particular an endomorphism $f\in\mathscr L(V,V)$ is called *Hermitian* if $f=f^*$ and *skew-Hermitian* if $f=-f^*$.

Clearly if $f$ is *skew-Hermitian* then
$$
\langle v,f(\vec v)\rangle=\langle f^*(\vec v),v\rangle=-\langle f(\vec v),v\rangle=-\langle\vec v,f(\vec v)\rangle
$$
for all $\vec v\in V$ and so $\langle v,f(\vec v)\rangle=0$ for all $v\in V$. But unfortunately I don't be able to proce that if $f$ is such that
$\langle v,f(\vec v)\rangle=0$ for all $v\in V$ then it is *skew-Hermitian*. So could someone hep me, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A common trick is to select two vectors $u$ and $v$ and apply the hypothesis to $u+v$. Using linearity you have
$$0 = \langle u+v,f(u+v) \rangle = \langle u,f(u) \rangle + \langle u,f(v) \rangle + \langle v,f(u) \rangle + \langle v,f(v) \rangle = \langle u,f(v) \rangle + \langle v,f(u) \rangle$$
so that
$$\langle u,f(v) \rangle = \langle -f(u),v\rangle.$$

Comment: Although is wasn't needed here, sometimes it helps also to consider vectors of the form $u + \alpha v$.